# Excel logic test considering several values of a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, logic

I have this file,:

```
ID Barcode
1  11
2  13
3  14
4  15
5  16
```

And I would like to do a logic function to know if the barcode values were recorded, for example, I enter the value 18 in another worksheet for conference, and the answer will be `not found` or I enter the value 11 and the answer will be `found`. 
I tried this:

```
IF(C1=B2:B6,"FOUND","NOT FOUND")
```

But doesn't work. Is it possible to this in excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, use iferror() with index() and match(). Enter the value you are looking for in cell C1 and cell C4 returns either not found or the ID number.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH(C1,$B$2:$B$6,0)),"Not Found")
```

See

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For example use:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D2,$B$2:$B$6,0)),"FOUND","NOT FOUND")
```

Or, if barcodes are unique:

```
=CHOOSE(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$6,D2)+1,"NOT FOUND","FOUND")
```

[image]

If returning `TRUE` or `FALSE` is good enough for you just use:

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$6,D2)>0
```

If your goal is to retrieve the ID when Barcode is found, then @SolarMike his suggestion with `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` is the way to go for sure.

Comment: You read the question better than I did :) but all these have uses.

Comment: @SolarMike, Ultimately I can see OP trying to return the ID, in which case you have given him the correct answer nonetheless ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are very close.  Just missing an `OR` and entering it as an array formula.

Your logical test is returning an array of comparisons:

```
C1: 14 ==>
{FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE}
```

But to determine if **ANY** of the returned values are `TRUE`, you need the `OR` function:

```
OR(C1=$B$2:$B$6)
```

Putting it all together, we have the **ARRAY** formula:

```
=IF(OR(C1=$B$2:$B$6),"Found","Not Found")
```

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

[image]